# Is it possible to use PLUpload in combination with CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, plupload

I am looking for some possibility of uploading images to my CouchDB and resizing them before the upload as long as they are still with the client. PLUpload offers a possibility for doing so but I wonder if it possible to use it together with CouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trying and reading I finally managed to upload a picture to CouchDB using PLUpload.
The main problem was that there is an undocumented property "file_data_name" which has to be set manually to fit with the needs from CouchDB. The default value is "name" but CouchDB is expecting "_attachments". I only found that property by inspecting the source code for the flash runtime.

Below there is the javascript I used for initializing the PLUpload:

```
$("form#pluploadForm #uploader").plupload({
  // General settings
  runtimes : 'flash,silverlight,html5',
  url : 'http://your.path.to.couchdb.com/database/[documentid]',
  max_file_size : '10mb',
  unique_names : true,
  file_data_name : "_attachments",

  // Resize images on clientside if we can
  resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},

  // Specify what files to browse for
  filters : [
    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
    {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
  ],

  // Flash settings
  flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

  // Silverlight settings
  silverlight_xap_url : 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap',

  multipart : true,
  multipart_params : {
    description: "uploadedViaPlupload",
   _rev: "[the current revision of your document]",
  }
});
```

But with this approach it is only possible to one image to one single document. Uploading to multiple documents isn't working but I didn't really try it (yet).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is override the BeforeUpload event of PLUploader to work with your couch instance before uploading the file.  In the method below, I am creating a new document (using jquery.couch.js), getting the response and using the new _id and _rev of the new document to set the PLUploader instance options.

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
  $db.saveDoc({
    users : ['all']
  }, {
    success : function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        up.settings.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/filesystem/' + response.id;
        up.settings.multipart_params._rev = response.rev;
        up.trigger("UploadFile", file);
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```